# What are the differences between `YEAR(OrderDate)` and `DATEPART(year,OrderDate)`

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

Assume `OrderDate` is a date. What are the differences between `YEAR(OrderDate)` and `DATEPART(year,OrderDate)` (or `DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate)` or `DATEPART(yy,OrderDate)` )? Thanks.

Comment: You should start with the documentation. DATEPART - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql and Year - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql

Comment: Have you read the documentation???  Before SQL Server 2008, you have to use `DATEPART` since there's no `YEAR()`.

Comment: @Eric - are you sure? I'm sure the functions such as `YEAR` existed at least as far back as 2000. Don't get confused by MS documentation that revises history and tells you the earliest *supported* version of the product (currently)

Comment: @Eric Don't believe the documentation when it says `SQL Server (starting with 2008)`, that is because the authors of the documentation don't usually bother to verify if any version prior to that supported the function. `year()` has been around for a long time, probably before it was called SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

They are all the same:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yy,GETDATE()), DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())
     , DATEPART(year, GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE());
```

As from doc

> year ->   yy, yyyy (abbreviations)

I would use `DATEPART` with `year` following EIBTI principle (Explicit Is Better than Implicit)

There is one more possibility `ODBC function`:

```
SELECT  {fn YEAR(GETDATE())};
```

---

For example to get `HOUR` you cannot use built-in function:

```
SELECT HOUR(GETDATE())
-- error

SELECT DATEPART(hour, GETDATE())
-- datepart function

SELECT {fn HOUR(GETDATE())}
-- will work
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XJO87364)**

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `DATEPART` because it is swiss-knife :)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that there are no functions for "HOUR", "MONTH", "DAY", ...? only "YEAR" for date value?

Comment: @Tim There are `YEAR/MONTH/DAY` but there aren't built-in `HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND/QUARTER` functions (of course you could use trick with `ODBC`)

Answer (score 1):

I try to consider compatibility with other language, including SQL flavors.  DATEPART is supported in other Microsoft products like C and VB.  But Year() is supported in MySQL.  So whcih to choose depends on your ecosystem and what you may end up migrating your code to.

Comment: As work continues on any project, and especially when dealing with datetime handling in SQL products, the chances of it being interoperable approaches zero. Fairly rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

**Just for fun**, DateName() returns the string value.

**Example**

```
Select 'Year '+datename(year,GetDate())
```

**Returns**

```
Year 2017
```